# AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)"

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using Afnetwork 2. I am a new one for IOS development. I want to connect some API using POST method.

In this API I want set the Header as well.

This is my code

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =[manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Auth-Token"];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"api/v1/contact-group/add/" parameters:params

    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {


    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {


    }];
```

When I use this code I am getting the error like this

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0xa8b0930 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxxxx.info/api/v1/contact-group/add, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), NSUnderlyingError=0xa88cb00 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html", AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xaa5a940> { URL: http://xxxxxx.info/api/v1/contact-group/add } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Thu, 12 Jun 2014 15:39:31 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "laravel_session=.....";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.28, PleskLin";
} }}
```

I refer lot of documents and stackoverflow questions and answer. They gave lot of answers. But Unfortunately I didn't get the solution. Please help me.

Please point my mistake.

NOTE: When I use without header it will return "Invalid header". It will return correct error message.

**EDIT**

Server expecting format
Method POST

```
input
{
    "blog_guid": "k39453050345j",
    "contact_groups": [
        "er234we232",
        "tet343i49ti3409t33"
    ]
}
```

server response

```
{
    "error": false,
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success"
}
```

I am sending parameters like this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                                   initWithObjects:@[guid, groupName, description]
                                   forKeys:@[APISEND_CONTACTGROUPKEY, APISEND_CONTACTGROUPNAME, APISEND_CONTACTGROUPDESCRIPTION]];
```

Comment: You're sending `text/html` content but seemingly the server is not expecting that kind of content (see its reply: "unacceptable content-type: text/html"). You might need to check the API you're dealing with and see what kind of data it is expecting (maybe JSON or XML?).

Comment: @romain API need JSON data.

Comment: I tried with sample API (without header) it is working

Comment: Did you try with ˋContent-Type: application/jsonˋ?

Comment: At this point I think you should post more information about the server: its API, the data it is expecting and also, the data type and content you're trying to send (your `params` variable).

Comment: @Romain Check the edited version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the elements you've added in your edited version, it seems like you're not sending out JSON data in the format that is expected by the server.

The server is expecting a dictionary with `blog_guid` and `contact_groups` items, the latter itself being an array of strings. You have to carefully comply with these requirements in your own code.

In your code, you're sending a dictionary with 3 items: `guid`, `groupName`, and `description`. Also, there are no arrays for the group names.

Try with something like this:

```
NSArray *groupNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:groupName];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                               initWithObjects:@[guid, groupNames]
                               forKeys:@[APISEND_BLOGGUID, APISEND_CONTACTGROUPKEY]];
```

Also, check that `APISEND_CONTACTGROUPKEY` equals to `@"contact_groups"` and `APISEND_BLOGGUID` equals to `@"blog_guid"`.

To help you debugging in case it still doesn't work, try to print out to the console the value of the `params` variable once it is serialized to JSON by AFNetworking, and check that it is similar to the format you've described in your question (the one that works).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're ok. Your server returns an error to your request. Code 500 usually means internal error such as unhandled exception. So it definitely has nothing to do with client.

Comment: Unless server is expecting POST request and you are sending another method (GET, PUT, DELETE...)